# Permalinks without subdirectories

Tags: permalinks

Today I use:

permalink_structure: /%postname%

This gives me URL like this on my pages:

1. #http://www.mypage.com/page1
2. #http://www.mypage.com/page1/page2
3. #http://www.mypage.com/page1/page2/page3

But I want it to be:

1. #http://www.mypage.com/page1
2. #http://www.mypage.com/page2
3. #http://www.mypage.com/page3

How can I make this happen?

I still want to use the parent function in wordpress admin...

**The reasons why I want this are:**

- It looks so much better
- When I (or some one else) change URL of page1 I am not messing
  up the URL for page 2 and page3 (less 301 work)
- (Better SEO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create all your pages as root pages and then use the Menu page in "Appearance -> Menus" to define the structure of the pages. This assumes that your theme supports Menus, which the default Wordpress themes TwentTen and TwentyEleven do.

**Update:**

Here's a couple of links that might help you do this without using the menus functionality (as I fully agree with your comment that it's a little annoying to use the menus functionality).

This is a plugin which seems like it might help:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

And here's an example of hacking the Wordpress core code (which I would generally not recommend):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-permalinks-without-hierarchy-parents

I haven't tried either though.

Comment: That's the best plan B :) A litle anoying for all sidebar menues for subpages tough.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of links that might help you avoid the menu functionality.

Comment: Thanks ZweiBlumen, actually I figure thath I will go with the "Menu page". In ONE menu I will structure the hole page structure. Then i will use RAW MySQL and PHP to make it function like this: Head menu = Level 1 (+ Level 2). Sidebar menu = Level 2 + 3 for current level 1 page. Will post it when I figure out how to do this :)